# Flask detected change when I did nothing?

Tags: security, flask, apache2

Ive turned a flask application into a API that returns a story formatted a specific way.

I get a lot of weird requests in the Flask log, like 'admin=1' etc.

Usually the application returns a 404 error code, but this time, the log is saying a detection was changed in the ssl python file. Here is the log:

```
45.77.209.114 - - [23/Nov/2017 18:24:40] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
45.77.209.114 - - [23/Nov/2017 18:24:40] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
45.77.209.114 - - [23/Nov/2017 18:24:40] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
45.77.209.114 - - [23/Nov/2017 18:24:40] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
45.77.209.114 - - [23/Nov/2017 18:24:40] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
45.77.209.114 - - [23/Nov/2017 18:24:40] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
 * Detected change in '/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py', reloading
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
```

Comment: The `admin=1` etc.., being passed in the URL might just be bots trying easy attacks on the server. Are you doing something that edits the `pyopenssl` file? Flask seems to be detecting the changes because that file gets edited.

Comment: I am not touching that file at all.